# i'm running Acquia Desktop, what exactly triggers the install.php page?

Tags: installation, acquia-dev-desktop

this keeps happening by mistake in various scenarios but once such scenario is this:

I'm doing some in-depth tutorials and required to drop all tables then do a massive SQL injection via PHPMyAdmin. And then additionally, replace the entire file system at the beginning of some lessons.

but instead of a populate website i get presented w/ the installer screen and don't know why. several times now i've had to start completely over.

what exactly triggers the install page? and considering i have a populated DB and file system, what steps do i need to take, or what should i be looking at to get he site to load?

Comment: The redirect usually happens when settings.php is missing/inaccessible

Answer (score 0):

I found it, at the very bottom of the settings file, if i put the code below back then the installer will NOT launch, which is what i want

```
//<DDSETTINGS>
// Please don't edit anything between <DDSETTINGS> tags.
// This section is autogenerated by Acquia Dev Desktop.
if (isset($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR']) &&     file_exists($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] .    '/loc_ravianatwo_local.inc'))
  require($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] .        '/loc_ravianatwo_local.inc');
//</DDSETTINGS>
```